# Connecting Spring boot to redis: NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/session/hazelcast/HazelcastFlushMode

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, redis, spring-session

So I have a spring boot app which I am trying to connect to a redis cluster hosted on AWS for the purposes of a session
Full error is:

```
  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.session-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionProperties': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionProperties]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/session/hazelcast/HazelcastFlushMode
```

In my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
}
   }

  apply plugin: 'java'
  apply plugin: 'eclipse'
  apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

   group = 'haughton.daniel'
  version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
  sourceCompatibility = 1.8

  repositories {
mavenCentral()
  }  


   ext {
springCloudVersion = 'Edgware.SR1'
     }
  processResources {
from ('.ebextensions/') {
    into '.ebextensions'
}
    }


   dependencies {

compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')

compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-mail', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'

compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')

compile group: 'org.thymeleaf.extras', name: 'thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'

compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.6'

compile group: 'org.springframework.session', name: 'spring-session-data-redis', version: '2.0.2.RELEASE'


compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile ('org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-dbcp:8.0.30')

runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
 }

 dependencyManagement {
imports {
    mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
}
  }
```

In my app.properties

```
 spring.session.store-type=redis
 spring.redis.host=my aws redis end point
 spring.redis.password=my password
 spring.redis.port=6379
```

I am following the guide here https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot-redis.html#boot-how

My security config

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration

public class SecurityConfiguration {
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http
                .antMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
    @Bean
    public EvaluationContextExtension securityExtension() {
        return new EvaluationContextExtensionSupport() {
            @Override
            public String getExtensionId() {
                return "security";
            }

            @Override
            public Object getRootObject() {
                Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
                return new SecurityExpressionRoot(authentication) {};
            }
        };
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService);
    }



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/web/login",
                "/web/forgotPassword",
                "/web/forgotPassword/useToken","/web/forgotPassword/**",
                "/web/forgotPassword/useToken/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/web/**").

                authenticated().
                and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/web/login")
                .permitAll()
                .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler())
                .failureUrl("/web/login-error")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/web/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/web/login")
                .and().
                csrf().disable();;

    }

    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler() {
        return (request, response, authentication) -> response.sendRedirect("/web");
    }


    @Bean
    public EvaluationContextExtension securityExtension() {
        return new EvaluationContextExtensionSupport() {
            @Override
            public String getExtensionId() {
                return "security";
            }

            @Override
            public Object getRootObject() {
                Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
                return new SecurityExpressionRoot(authentication) {};
            }
        };
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Which version of Spring Session are you using? It isn't obvious from your code snippets.

Comment: I am just using spring-data-redis', version: '2.0.6.RELEASE' as thats what the tutorial said

Comment: The tutorial that you linked doesn't reference `spring-data-redis` at all, but rather Spring Session's `spring-session-data-redis`.

Comment: My mistake,I was fiddling with things and put in spring-data-redis,I initially had spring-session-data-redis,I have just confirmed my code is up to date wth spring-session-data-redis and edited my post to be accurate of my build.gradle,the error I am getting is what is originally in the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using incompatible versions of Spring Boot and Spring Session.

Spring Boot 1.5 is aligned with Spring Session 1.3, as can be seen in [dependency versions appendix](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.12.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions) of Spring Boot's reference manual. OTOH, Spring Boot 2.0 is aligned with Spring Session 2.0, as can be seen [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions).

You should really avoid using explicit dependency version declarations in your build script, and rely on dependency management provided by Spring Boot, unless there's good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: ahhh so if I just do // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.session/spring-session-data-redis
compile group: 'org.springframework.session', name: 'spring-session-data-redis' it will automatically select the correct one?

Comment: Yes, you can simply do `compile 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-data-redis'` as you do with some of your other dependencies.